# Android, Iphone, Windows and Blackberry API search apps

Tags: api, blackberry, app-store, google-play, windows-phone

Is it possible to search apps via API on:
1. Android Market
2. App Store
3. Windows Phone App Store
4. Blackberry App World
5. Facebook App Store

and if so, can you provide specific links to that sections (not only to the develops pages)?

Thanks

Comment: This is 5 separate questions.

Comment: I know, can you answer me or I have to open 5 different questions?

Comment: You should open 5 different questions.  No single answer will cover this question, so it's not currently in a good form for StackOverflow.

Comment: I can't open 5 different questions here because it says that i'm opening duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use google api, or some simple stuff
for example you want to search games in android market place 
get the result of this
games site: https://play.google.com/
in google.com

Answer (score 0):

```css
For Apple App store---

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=+<appname>+&entity=software

There are no public apis are available for Android, Windows, Blackberry.

Paid API For Android Apps--

42Matters

For Windows, Backberry, Facebook--

Do web scrapping by using CSQuery(or) html agility pack..
```